# Plugin activated but not working in wordpress on desktop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress plugins & running wordpress on my wamp server on my laptop and I have written & activated this on my wordpress site (site name: lifyog) on the same server on my desktop. Function written in plugin is supposed to add image with every post, however it is not working. Please help in correcting the code.

I have checked the image source this is ok.

My plugin is at following address:

```
wamp/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/Wpplugin
```

File name is `addimage.php`

Code of plugin is as under:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Add Image
Plugin URL:http//wordpress
Version: 1.0
Author: wordpress
Author URL: http://localhost/wordpress
Description: This plugin automatically adds an image at the beginning of every post
*/

function addImage($post)
{
$imagewithtext="<img src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/Images/veer.jpg' height='70px' width='70px' align='left'>";
$imagewithtext=$post;
return $imagewithtext;

}

add_filter("the_content","addImage");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $imagewithtext variable declare on line 14 is overwriting the $imagewithtext variable that you have wrote on the line 13.

You can change the equal sign "=" to dot equal sign ".=", this will help you to add the $post variable value to $imagewithtext variable and not overwrite it

`$imagewithtext .= $post;` not `$imagewithtext = $post;`

I believe this will do the trick